# Select Query To Get Last 9 Months Data in SQLite3

Tags: python, select, sqlite

Im working on project for school in python. I need to do (Query) report that give the front disk of a hotel a list of guests who stayed at the hotel 9 months before the current day from one table in SQLite Database. I couldn't know how to do the 'where' condition to get the previous 9 months data :(

BTW the database is SQLite3.

Any help will be great

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're here to help, but we're not here to do your work for you. You need to put some effort into solving it yourself first.

Comment: I tried this: 
    <pre>    SELECT * FROM GuestInfo WHERE strftime(Arrival) <= strftime(julianday())    <code>
Which return all the previous data. what i need is to return ONLY the data for the last 9 months before the current day. 

Sorry don't know how to format the select statement :(
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without giving you the answer (because you need to do some work yourself), this should gvie you a starting point.

```
SELECT * FROM GuestInfo 
WHERE ArrivalDate >= (Today's date - your definition of 9 months before today)
```

Comment: here is what i did:
<pre>    select name from guestinfo where
arrival >  (select date ('now', '-9 months')) and checkout <=  (select date ('now'))    <code>

It's work 100% when I run it in the SQLite and give correct result, but when I run it in the Python shill, it give me invalid error in 'now' the one in the date. Could anyone help me with that?? Is there any other way to write the current date?? 

the error in this part: (select date ('now', '-9 months'))